# vba multi cells error 450

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

i have this code to copy from one work book to another and seems to work well when i use something like A1:A23 however i need to copy certain cells but i get a run time error 450 the debug shows this.

```
 Workbooks(Dir(Path)).Worksheets("DCR").range("A3", "A9", "A19" "A23" "B38:B44").VALUE = _
   Workbooks("book.xlsm").Worksheets("dcr").range("L3", "L9", "L19" "L23" "M38:M44").VALUE
```

if i take all the " out it just copys the value from A3 to all the cells
any help would be great

Comment: you have posted an invalid range reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't assign value or copy-paste to disjointed cells in one line.  you will need to separate each group into its own line.

The best method is to use a With Block and making the other ws a variable, to limit the typing.

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Workbooks("book.xlsm").Worksheets("dcr")
With Workbooks(Dir(Path)).Worksheets("DCR")
    .range("A3").Value = ws.range("L3").Value
    .range("A9").Value = ws.range("L9").Value
    .range("A19").Value = ws.range("L19").Value
    .range("A23").Value = ws.range("L23").Value
    .range("B38:B44").Value = ws.range("M38:M44").Value 
End With
```